# Writing web based .txt content into excel using Python

Tags: python, excel

Very new to Python and more questions as I go along. To summarize, the objective is to pull .txt content from a HTML site onto excel and subsequently send it out on email using Python and/or Excel Macros.

For now, I have managed to pull out the content using the following code.

```
import requests
response = requests.get("https://www.ams.usda.gov/mnreports/wa_gr101.txt")
txt=response.text
lines = txt.split('\n') 
print(lines[25])
```

My first question question is how to write that content into an ***existing*** excel .xlsx file. Most suggestions online (xlsxwriter or DataFrame) writes the data into a new excel file and sheet that have names defined within Python.

```
import xlsxwriter 
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("xxx.xlsx")
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("New sheet")
worksheet.write('A2', "xxx")
workbook.close()
```

My second question is that even when I write a line using the suggested methods (xlsxwriter or DataFrame), the text in the new spreadsheet only contains the first word instead of the entire row of of data. Is there a way around this?

Thank you for your help.

Cheers and happy...Monday....

Ad

Answer (score 0):

I'll start by noting that it would be helpful if you provide the code for your existing attempts at a solution (using xlsxwriter).

Otherwise, I will urge you to consider using the [openpyxl](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/index.html/) as it can load existing workbooks and worksheets, and it should allow you to iterate over your list like so (based on my guess of your desired output):

```
#where destSheet is an openpyxl sheet object that you have loaded
for lineNum,rowNum in enumerate(range(startrow, startrow+len(lines), 1):
    destSheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=1).value = lines[lineNum]
```

Comment: Hi Konchshell, I have included the xlsx writer codes on to the original text. Thanks for your help. I will try your suggested method...

Comment: Thanks for adding that, my best guess is that the xlsxwriter package must be seeing each string in your list as a "list of words" and is only capturing the first item, but I could be wrong. Let me know if my openpyxl suggestion leads to a resolution for you!

Comment: Hi again, I have only managed to import the workbook. Python keeps producing this error message "list index out of range" whenever I input the following code:                                                                            import openpyxl
xfile = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx')
sheet = xfile.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
sheet['A1'] = 'hello world'
xfile.save('text2.xlsx')

Comment: It would help if you provide the traceback for the error, as I am unable determine which line produces it.

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-87-e3df9ce2fa55> in <module>()
      2 wb = Workbook("xxxyyy.xlsm")
      3 
----> 4 ws = wb.active(0)

C:\......\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py in active(self)
    107     def active(self):
    108         """Get the currently active sheet"""
--> 109         return self._sheets[self._active_sheet_index]
    110 
    111     @active.setter